# SharePoint Designer 2010 Out of Box Approval Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am using SharePoint Designer (SPD) 2010 Approval Workflow. I have a Lib with two people fields. Approver 1 and Approver 2. I want to pass these values to SPD 2010 Approval Workflow (Instead of doing hardcoded on Approval Stages in browser) so that I can assign approver dynamically. my SPD 2010 OOTB WF is not receiving the approvers from the form. Email is always sent to person who initiate the request and gets the message that "Instead of xxx person assiggning the Task to "originator"

Can you please provide me the solution on this

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any easy way you will be able to do this. I would advise you rethink your workflow?

Perhaps you could just use the standard approval workflow (library settings -> workflow settings -> create new workflow (approval)) - there is an option when setting this up to allow users to specify who they want the approvers to be. So when the user starts the workflow manually, they can choose who the approvers are. This might fit your needs?